# modal aparecer depois de notficaçao

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Colegas.

Tenho um chat em um projeto, porém quero ir mais além. Quero que o usuário I ao chamar o usuário II receba uma notificaçao do modal bootstrap. A ideia inicial é criar status no banco de dados e o usuário II ao receber o convite, mudaria o status, por ex. C de convite e apareceria o modal. Então quero colocar dentro de uma div uma chamada ex.:

```
if($statusChamada == 'C'){
?>
<div id='chamada'>Abrir o modal</div>
<?php } ?>
```

e o Jquey:

```
setInterval(function() {
$("#chamada").load(location.href+" #chamada");
}, 1000);
```

Até aqui tudo bom, tudo bem... mas como faria para que o modal do bootstrap abrisse automaticamente?

Comment: Você já tem o código que consulta o banco e verifica se tem uma chamada pendente ou não?

Comment: Sim... está tudo construído... só preciso modal abrir automaticamente....

Comment: Você quer que quando a `div` **chamada** aparecer o modal seja aberto também? (pra ver se entendi rsrs)

Comment: Olá Luíne... Isso... o modal abrir quando a div for chamada...Falta só isso para terminar essa etapa do projeto...rs

Comment: @Fox.11 Como você já verifica o status entre intervalos, quando a condição for satisfeita executa um onclick no id do <button> que chama o modal.